# http request with params

Tags: http, request, dart, flutter, http-request-parameters

Is there some function that adds the request params to an http request in way that you don't have to do it "manually"? For example, if I want to put `"user": "x"` as param of my request, in a way to achieve something like

```
http:test/testing?user=x
```

how can I do it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't add params to a request, you need to add it to an URL you use for the request. The Uri class provides methods for that

```
var uri = Uri.parse('http://test/testing');
uri = uri.replace(query: 'user=x');
print(uri);
```

or

```
uri = uri.replace(queryParameters: <String, String>{'user': 'x'});
```

or

```
final uri = Uri.parse('http://test/testing').replace(query: 'user=x');
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a more direct way to do it is to use [`Uri.http`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Uri/Uri.http.html).

```
// http://example.org/path?q=dart.
Uri.http("example.org", "/path", { "q" : "dart" });
```

**Notes:**

- The query parameters are `{ "q" : "dart" }`.
- `Uri.https()` works the same way.